# Hypothetical Testing in Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test- Whether critical value or p value

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-test, kolmogorov-smirnov

I am new to Statistics.
I am trying out one sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test. I was able to find till D max. But I am confused to move forward for Hypothesis Testing.

Inorder to determine the Hypothesis should I move forward with --

Critical value from table

Rejected if the test statistic, D, is greater than the critical value obtained from a table

or

p value of KS Statustic value .

Which one is better?Read that p Value is better.
In [this](http://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/kstest.html) they tell
"*kstest decides to reject the null hypothesis by comparing the p-value p with the significance level Alpha, not by comparing the test statistic ksstat with the critical value cv. Since cv is approximate, comparing ksstat with cv occasionally leads to a different conclusion than comparing p with Alpha.*"

But couldn't find any equation regarding to the same.

[Reference](https://src.alionscience.com/pdf/K_STest.pdf)

In the above reference I doubt if they are taking D max as p value.

Please advice

Comment: Down voters please comment so that I can improve my question

Answer (score 0):

*Quick answer*: using the critical value and the p-value will always give the same conclusion.

*Details*:

The p-value is the probability that the test statistic is greater than the critical value, if the null hypothesis is true.

Alpha is the pre-determined acceptable **false positive rate**. **You** decide this. It will affect your **decision** to reject or not, but will not change the numerical values of the p-value or test statistic.

Whether you decide to reject or not based on the critical value or the p-value, you should and will **always get the same result**. If the critical value is approximate, then so is the p-value.